# Calendar Control in WPF weird behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, wpf-controls

I am trying Bind the "DisplayDate" of the calendar to make the control notify whenever there is change in date.

Here is my xaml

```
<Window x:Class="CalenderControl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>        
            <Calendar x:Name="_calendar" DisplayMode="Year"  DisplayDate="{Binding Display}"/>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and my ViewModel

```
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }

        private DateTime _displayDate;

        public DateTime Display
        {
            get { return _displayDate; }
            set { _displayDate = value; OnPropertyChanged("Display"); }
        }

    }
```

**CASE 1:**

After all this.  I have assigned the datacontext with viewmodel.

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new ViewModel() { Display = DateTime.Parse("10/10/2015") };
        }
```

This is how it looks after binding.

[image: Image Binded with DisplayDAte]

**CASE 2:**

Then, I tried without assigning the DataContext with ViewModel.

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // --- Commenting out ---
            //this.DataContext = new ViewModel() { Display = DateTime.Parse("10/10/2015") };  
        }
```

This is how it looks without binding

[image: Without Binding]

Why the width goes weird when I assign the DataContext?  Is there anything I'm doing wrong. .

Comment: it should be  OnPropertyChanged("Display"); not  OnPropertyChanged("DisplayDate");  in the setter.(not related to width problem)

Comment: @Nikita. . Yes. Updated now.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an unknown reason the issue seems to be related to `DisplayMode="Year"`

I can suggest you to do the following steps, seems working in my test app.

1) Remove DisplayMode from your Xaml
2) After setting the DataContext, append this:

```
  Action act = delegate()
  {
    _calendar.SelectedDate = ((ViewModel)DataContext).Display;
    _calendar.DisplayMode = CalendarMode.Year;
    _calendar.SelectedDate = null;
  };
  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(act, DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
```

Seems weird but it should work. You couldn't set SelectedDate back to null if you need it.

Added: The SelectedDate tricks seems necessary to set your Calendar Date to 2015, in your screenshot is year 1 ;-)

Comment: Hurray. .  Its working as expected. . Thanks alot.  Still it I am perplexed about the behavior.

Comment: Very very strange....but this seems to do the trick! Feel free to accept the answer if helped you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the `DisplayDate` binding that is causing the `Calendar` control to stretch; it is setting the `DisplayMode` to "`Year`". It looks like a bug in the `Calendar` control.